# aws cli get error "The security token included in the request is invalid"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I did `aws configure` and test it worked before. But it didn't work today, I got the the error when tried to get hosted zone

```
 $ aws route53 list-hosted-zones

 An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the ListHostedZones operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I deleted ~/.aws and did `aws configure` again, but I still got the same error.
Could you please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have MFA enabled on your account?  You might have to run

```
aws sts get-session-token
```

Details for how to use MFA with the cli are documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/).

Comment: i get `An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid` when trying to run `aws sts get-session-token`

Comment: @Raksha same for me. have you found a solution?

Comment: for @emily.mi and possibly Raksha:  see the answer from Ken Roy below, you may be trying to use an access key that's gone "inactive" due to, well, inactivity.  Re-activating the existing key will be required in that case.

Answer (score 11):

After you enabled MFA, you will have to pass temporary credentials you received from executing 
 `aws sts get-session-token` on each future request.

With environment variables:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YYY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=ZZZ
```

With named profiles:

```
[mfa]
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYY
aws_session_token = ZZZ
```

**The** `An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) ...` **error might occur again and again if you forget to remove the previous temporary credentials.**

So, if you're using environment variables don't forget to unset all variables before new execution of `aws sts get-session-token`:

```
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

If you're using named profiles - don't forget to update the profile under `.aws/credentials`.

Answer (score 2):

I threw this together as having to do this all the time was very annoying. Im no shell developer but this works for me by using `source /path/to/this/script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
​
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
​
AWS_CREDS=$(aws sts get-session-token)
​
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(jq -r '.[].AccessKeyId' <<< "${AWS_CREDS}")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(jq -r '.[].SecretAccessKey' <<< "${AWS_CREDS}")
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='YOUR_REGION'
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(jq -r '.[].SessionToken' <<< "${AWS_CREDS}")
AWS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION=$(jq -r '.[].Expiration' <<< "${AWS_CREDS}")
​
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
​
echo "Tokens generated and saved to this terminal session. Tokens will expire on ${AWS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION}"
```

Answer (score 2):

After receiving this error and logging in via browser I saw the my IAM User "Access Key" was "inactive".  After activating it (from that same view) I was able to use aws and aws-vault.