# Create an IAM Role that makes Redshift able to access S3 bucket (ReadOnly)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I'm trying to create a new IAM role and attach the S3 Read only Access policy but when I'm running the below code. I'm getting the following error: **An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.**

I have set up the correct aws access key and security key in the configuration file but still I'm not able to get through this error.

Code for creating the IAM role.

```
try:
    print('1.1 Creating a new IAM Role')
    dwhRole = iam.create_role(
        Path='/',
        RoleName=DWH_IAM_ROLE_NAME,
        Description='Allows Redshift clusters to call AWS services on your behalf.',
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument=json.dumps({
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": {
                    "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
                  },
                  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
              ]
            }),
    )

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# TODO: Attach Policy
print('1.2 Attaching Policy')
iam.attach_role_policy(RoleName=DWH_IAM_ROLE_NAME,
                       PolicyArn="arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"
                      )['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']

# TODO: Get and print the IAM role ARN
print('1.3 Get the IAM role ARN')
roleArn = iam.get_role(RoleName=DWH_IAM_ROLE_NAME)['Role']['Arn']

print(roleArn)
```

DWH_IAM_ROLE_NAME is a variable which is defined the configuration file as well.

Comment: Do you have MFA enabled on your account?

Comment: yes, I have just enabled it.

Comment: Try to unset your AWS env variables and get a new session token by running the sts command `aws sts get-session-token`.

Comment: But do I have to put the session token as well while creating the iam role? I'm stuck very badly. Do you have any resources which I can follow?

Comment: There are many questions similar to yours. Please check the answer to those questions. For eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034903/an-error-occurred-invalidclienttokenid-when-calling-the-assumerole-operation , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582318/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-inval , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198127/aws-cli-get-error-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-invalid

Comment: `unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN; aws sts get-session-token;`

Comment: Then run `aws configure` to reset the id, key and token value

Comment: did this solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help Arpit, I unset the env variables and generated new ones and set those   in a new profile. Then I created the IAM user and I was able to do so. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, unset the below env variables:-

```
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Get a new session token and save it or copy it to your clipboard:-

```
aws sts get-session-token
```

Run the below command and it is ask for SECRET KEY, ID, TOKEN

```
aws configure
```

Finally, re-run your script.